# Crash reporter for iOS framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I have published a cocoapod and would like to get notifications when code in my pod crashes in client apps. Is this possible. My cocoapod is a swift framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to setup crash reporting that only works for a framework (or static library). The required signal handlers and uncaught exception handler will always work for the whole app process and its loaded frameworks.

In addition it is only possible to have one signal handler setup per app process, so if you add one in your framework that would overwrite the app signal handler and you would get all crash reports for the app and the app developer likely none.

If you want crashes that are related to your framework, ask your users to provide them.

Comment: Any reason why in principle Fabric or others could not add a method that allows the client app to say "any crashes detected in Framework X, send to the framework developer's Fabric account whose key is Y" ?